# How to gracefully handle nil checking, with optional paramter values?

Tags: xcode, swift

I have the following code:

```
@IBAction func search(sender: AnyObject) {
    let searchWord = searchQ.text
    let r = searchRadius.text
    let latitude = searchLat.text
    let longitude = searchLon.text
    customSearch(searchWord!, radius: r!, lat: latitude!, lon: longitude!)
}
```

the method `customSearch` has default parameters set in case the user doesn't put anything in, so...

how can I CHECK if searchWord, r, latitude and longitude are nil. If they are nil, then use customSearch functions default parameters, otherwise, use whichever ones were provided and fill out the rest with default values?

Oh and to elaborate, apparently if I take the value of a textfield, and it's empty, it's not nil but an empty string.. so I added the following:

```
func customSearch(q:String = "", radius:String = "25", lat:String = "33.960", lon:String = "-118.4179") {
    let geoSearchWord = (q == "" ? q : "geoSearchWord=\(q)")
    let geoSearchLat = (lat == "" ? "33.960" : "&geoSearchWordLat=\(lat)")
    let geoSearchLon = (lon == "" ? "-118.4179" : "&geoSearchWordLon=\(lon)")
    let geoSearchRadius = (radius == "" ? "25" : "&geoSearchWordRadius=\(radius)")

    let twitterURLRequest: String = "https://quiet-cove-5048.herokuapp.com/tw?\(geoSearchWord)\(geoSearchLat)\(geoSearchLon)\(geoSearchRadius)"
    alamoRequest(twitterURLRequest)
}
```

but I'm still not happy with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if-let`:

```
@IBAction func search(sender: AnyObject) {

    if  let searchWord = searchQ.text,
            r = searchRadius.text,
            latitude = searchLat.text,
            longitude = searchLon.text {
        customSearch(searchWord, radius: r, lat: latitude, lon: longitude)
    }
}
```

the `customSearch` method will be executed only if all four `lets` are found to be not `nil`. Your code will thus be guaranteed to execute safely without crashing.

**Moreover**

What the changes to your method `customSearch` do is to specify default parameters, IF certain parameters are *not passed at all* while invoking the method. It won't work if you pass nil instead.
For instance, if you call `customSearch()`, without passing any parameter values, all 4 params will take default values, and so on.

If you are okay with having nil values in the parameters, change your `customSearch` method implementation as follows:

```
func customSearch(q:String?, radius:String?, lat:String?, lon:String?) {
    let geoSearchWord = (q == nil ? "" : "geoSearchWord=\(q)")
    let geoSearchLat = (lat == nil ? "33.960" : "&geoSearchWordLat=\(lat)")
    let geoSearchLon = (lon == nil ? "-118.4179" : "&geoSearchWordLon=\(lon)")
    let geoSearchRadius = (radius == nil ? "25" : "&geoSearchWordRadius=\(radius)")

    let twitterURLRequest: String = "https://quiet-cove-5048.herokuapp.com/tw?\(geoSearchWord)\(geoSearchLat)\(geoSearchLon)\(geoSearchRadius)"
    alamoRequest(twitterURLRequest)
}
```

The `?` next to the parameter type allows them to be nil.

Finally, while invoking the method, make sure you don't fore unwrap any of the params, like so:

```
    @IBAction func search(sender: AnyObject) {
        customSearch(searchQ.text, radius: searchRadius.text, lat: searchLat.text, lon: searchLon.text)
    }
```

Comment: Well the thing is, I'm okay with any or all values being nil. That's why I'd have default parameters. Meaning, if you pass in nil, then it'll go to the default, otherwise it'll use the value provided. And this isn't the case where all four are not nil, one or two or three or all four can be nil, in any combination.

Comment: Edited. Now any or all of the params can be nil. Also, while invoking the methods, leave the params optional by not force-unwrapping any of the `.text` properties of the textfields.

Comment: Yeah that's essentially what I did, but thanks will give you the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for your implementation not to use default parameters inside `customSearch` function?

If so you could try something like this

```
@IBAction func search(sender: AnyObject) {
    let searchWord = searchQ.text ?? "defaultWord"
    let r = searchRadius.text ?? "defaultR"
    let latitude = searchLat.text ?? "defaultLatitude"
    let longitude = searchLon.text ?? "defaultLongitude"
    customSearch(searchWord, radius: r, lat: latitude, lon: longitude)
}

// where customSearch function might look like this
func customSearch(word: String, radius: String, lat: String, lon: String) {

   /*...*/
}
```

Another way would be to move this logic inside your `customSearch` function:

```
@IBAction func search(sender: AnyObject) {
    let searchWord = searchQ.text
    let r = searchRadius.text
    let latitude = searchLat.text
    let longitude = searchLon.text
    customSearch(searchWord, radius: r, lat: latitude, lon: longitude)
}

// where customSearch function might look like this
func customSearch(word: String?, radius: String?, lat: String?, lon: String?) {

    let searchWord = word ?? "defaultWord"
    let r = radius ?? "defaultR"
    let latitude = lat ?? "defaultLatitude"
    let longitude = lon ?? "defaultLongitude"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, default parameters in functions appear to be all or nothing. Effectively, you have two function signatures: one which uses the defaults, and the other that doesn't.

If `customSearch` is a function that you control, you could rewrite it to accept optional parameters, and assign the defaults inside the function implementation.